# Ports for ruby gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So the location I have my rails server setup by default blocks all ports outbound. I need to provide a list of ports to open for my Rails server and RVM to work.

What ports I need to be opened?

Answer (score 2):

rvm uses https to download ruby binaries. (so port 443). Vaguely possible I suppose that some dependencies only available over http

bundler will download gems over https where possible (port 443), although if you have any gems that are configured to be fetched from github, those may be using ssh (port 22), although it is possible to change the urls to fetcher those over https too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open the port from which the Rails application is running. RVM and Ruby Gems primarily depend on HTTP/HTTPS per your specification, so you'll need to have the ports 80 and 443 respectively opened for outbound requests.

Components may also be downloaded git, which uses SSH on port 22 by default. You can instead configure git to use HTTPS (443) also with the following command if for some reason you'd rather not open another port:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

By default, Rails will run on port 3000 when you launch your app with the command `rails server`. You can also set it to the port of your choosing with the `-p` flag.  You'll need this port open for inbound requests.

From `rails server --help`:

```
Usage: rails server [mongrel, thin, etc] [options]
    -p, --port=port                  Runs Rails on the specified port.
                                     Default: 3000
```

If you specify that a

Comment: That is for the server but I am asking about when I do a bundle install, what ports is that using to go download the gems